# Check for Numeric Value in Word Macro using Regular Expressions

Tags: regex, vba, ms-word

Is it possible to directly use regular expressions in Word macros?

I want to check if a string contains only numbers and the following code does not work.

```
isNumber = RegEx.IsMatch("234", "[0-9]+$")
```

I simply need it to return true or false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an instance of the `VBScript.Regexp` object within your code, but an easier solution would be to use the existing VBA function `IsNumeric`.  Both methods are included below:

```
Sub testNumeric()

    'Use IsNumeric
    MsgBox (IsNumeric("12345"))     'Returns true
    MsgBox (IsNumeric("123a"))      'Returns false

    'Alternatively, using Regexp Object
    Dim regexp
    Set regexp = CreateObject("VBScript.Regexp")
    regexp.Pattern = "[0-9]+$"
    MsgBox (regexp.test("12345"))   'Returns true
    MsgBox (regexp.test("123a"))   'Returns false

End Sub
```

Note that the regex pattern does not strictly return numbers, but also any string that ends with numbers (i.e. testing "a123" returns true).  To make the regex check strictly numeric, the pattern could be `^[0-9]+$`.  Thanks to @mike for pointing this out.