# Use VBA regular expression in Word Find/Replace macro?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I often use a legacy text editor (Vim) to take meeting notes because I can keep up with the talking.  However, most people (including myself) prefer the final notes to be in Word, with bullets and sub-bullets.  Here is an example of a text file that I wanted to convert to Word bullets:

```
Meeting notes
-------------
 * The quick brown fox
 * The quick brown fox
    - Jumped over the lazy dogs
    - Jumped over the lazy dogs
 * The quick brown fox
```

I recorded a macro to convert text bullets to Word bullets.  Any paragraph starting with text bullet "`*`" gets converted to "List Bullet 2", then I globally replace "`*`" with "" (i.e., deleted).  Any paragraph starting with the more indented text bullet "   `-`" gets converted to "List Bullet 4", then I globally delete "   `-`".  The "BulletsTxt2wrd" macro is shown below.

The problem is, I use Word's Find/Replace function, which can't really restrict the search of the above strings to the beginning of a paragraph.  If there is a "`*`" in the middle of the paragraph (perhaps "`25 * 3.1415`"), the same paragraph formatting and deletion occurs.

Regular expressions can confine searches to the start of a paragraph.  I used regular expressions in a unix environment, and after years of reading that it can be done in VBA, I used it in simple Excel function to convert time durations specified in days/minutes to hours.  For example (see "DurtnStr2hrs" function below:

- "20 hours" becomes 20
- "1 hour" becomes 1
- "1 day" becomes 24
- "3 days" becomes 3*24
- "1 minute" becomes 1/60
- "70 minutes" becomes 70/60

I use this function within a spreadsheet cell, with the argument being another cell containing the string to be converted.

**Is there a way to use the regular expression package and objects in the "BulletsTxt2wrd" Word macro?**  It seems to function like a black box, and the VBA code doesn't really expose the object property containing the string that I want to operate on.

P.S. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50274476/using-vba-regular-expressions-to-find-replace-in-word) doesn't deal with the Find/Replace method that I recorded, which goes through the entire document to locate matches.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22210995/check-for-numeric-value-in-word-macro-using-regular-expressions) refers to VBScript, but I really would like to avoid having to figure out another language to accomplish my simple task.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30719710/regular-expression-in-word-vba) also doesn't use the Find/Replace recorded in my macro.

---

```
Sub BulletsTxt2wrd()
'
' BulletsTxt2wrd Macro
'
'
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("List Bullet 2")
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = " * "
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = " * "
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("List Bullet 4")
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "    - "
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "    - "
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub
```

---

```
Function DurtnStr2hrs(str) As Double
   ' Use for DurtnHrs column
   Dim NewStr As String
   Dim regex1 As Object
   Set regex1 = New RegExp
   NewStr = str
   regex1.Pattern = " hours?"
   NewStr = regex1.Replace(NewStr, "")
   regex1.Pattern = " minutes?"
   NewStr = regex1.Replace(NewStr, "/60")
   regex1.Pattern = " days?"
   NewStr = regex1.Replace(NewStr, "*24")
   DurtnStr2hrs = Evaluate(NewStr)
End Function
```

Comment: You need to use the wildcards option in Find. See the article [Finding and replacing characters using wildcards](https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/General/UsingWildcards.htm) on the Word MVP's site for details.

Comment: Please explain the logic behind «"20 hours" becomes 24*60» what would '3 hours' become? A single *wildcard* Find, with .Text = "<[0-9]@ [dh][ao][yu]*>" would find all the combinations and a Select Case statement in a loop in the macro (see my separate answer) could handle the conversions without the need for a separate function.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt: O.M.G. Such a rich resource. I'm not sure if it solves my problem, but it will be handy in the future. Thank you.

Comment: @macropod: Thanks for pointing out my typo.  I've fixed it.  I have to find some time in the day to digest your answer.  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is, I use Word's Find/Replace function, which can't really restrict the search of the above strings to the beginning of a paragraph

Au contraire, you could use the `^` anchor, like:

```
Sub Demo1()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "^13[ *-]{1,}"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Format = False
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .MatchWildcards = True
  End With
  Do While .Find.Execute
    .Start = .Start + 1
    Select Case Trim(.Text)
      Case "*": .Paragraphs.Last.Style = wdStyleListBullet2
      Case "-": .Paragraphs.Last.Style = wdStyleListBullet4
    End Select
    .Text = vbNullString
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
  Loop
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

As for the `DurtnStr2hrs` conversion, I note there remains a disconnect between your text description of `"20 hours" becomes 20*60` and your Regex of `NewStr = regex1.Replace(NewStr, "/60")`. That said, try:

```
Sub Demo2()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "<[0-9]@ [dh][ao][yu]*>"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Format = False
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .MatchWildcards = True
  End With
  Do While .Find.Execute
    .Start = .Start + 1
    Select Case Split(.Text, " ")(1)
      Case "hour": .Text = Split(.Text, " ")(0)
      Case "hours": .Text = Split(.Text, " ")(0) & "/60"
      Case "day": .Text = "24"
      Case "days": .Text = Split(.Text, " ")(0) & "*24"
    End Select
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
  Loop
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. It didn't do anything until I straddled `*` with a pair of spaces. I've updated my original question to show these spaces and provide a swath of text to which the macro should apply. With the straddling spaces, `wdStyleListBullet2` was successfully applied, but the leading text still includes `*` preceded by a space. I added `Debug.Print(".Characters.Last=_"+.Characters.Last+"_")` in the loop and saw that `Last` contained only `*` (no spaces). So I'm not sure why one of t0he two spaces got deleted. Is there any way to force it to include both spaces in " * "?

Comment: I've always thought that `^p` at the beginning of a search expression represented the paragraph ending of the preceding paragraph. The acid test will be to see that applying `List Bullet 4` does not have any side effects on a preceding `List Bullet 2` paragraph.

Comment: Thanks, macropod.  I confirmed that Demo1 works, and Demo2 does seem to have the advantage of not requiring the regular expression package.  To me, Demo2 is for educational purposes because I don't really need to solve that problem anymore, it was just an example of how I managed to use regular expressions. The problem arose from copying and pasting Outlook Journal entries in List view to Excel. I found that if I exported it to CSV instead, the durations are all in minutes.

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to do the job:

```
Sub BulletTxt2doc()
doL1bullet:
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "^p * "
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        Selection.Find.Execute
        If .Found = True Then
            Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine
            Selection.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("List Bullet 2")
            Selection.MoveUp Unit:=wdParagraph, Count:=1
            Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdWord, Count:=2, Extend:=wdExtend
            Selection.Delete Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
            GoTo doL1bullet
        End If
    End With
doL2bullet:
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "^p    - "
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        Selection.Find.Execute
        If .Found = True Then
            Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine
            Selection.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("List Bullet 4")
            Selection.MoveUp Unit:=wdParagraph, Count:=1
            Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdWord, Count:=2, Extend:=wdExtend
            Selection.Delete Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
            GoTo doL2bullet
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Using Selection is awful. Aside from producing loads of screen flicker, it's horribly slow. The code in my answer shows how to do things efficiently and with no screen flicker.